# How to change a file extension to uppercase in CVS?

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I have a **test.cab** file in my CVS repository. How can I change the extension of this file to uppercase so that it will be **test.CAB**. I can commit my file in CVS with an uppercase extension to rewrite previous one. But rewriting doesn't actually happen. And when someone check out this file from cvs they get an old one, I mean **test.cab**.

I cannot change the filename. So can I rewrite it anyhow?

I use Eclipse CVS plugin but can install other cvs client if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In windows this is hard as test.CAB and test.cab are considered to be the same file.

The way I've done this in the past is to do it in two steps. First rename it to testtmp.CAB then commit that then rename it to test.CAB and commit that.